# How to associate files of a type to a particular extension always in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

If we have multiple extensions installed on vscode that support a particular file type (example - .ico files). When a file of this type (.ico file) is opened, how is the language to be associated with the file decided?

Is there a way for an extension to have files of a particular type always get associated with it, even if there are multiple other extensions that support this file are installed?